# What exactly does the enable-background attribute do?

Tags: svg

What exactly does the `enable-background` attribute do?

I read the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/filters.html#AccessingBackgroundImage) but still I don't understand it.

Answer (score 127, accepted):

> It has been deprecated by all major browsers since 2014

It's supposed to make the background image available to child elements of the element it's specified on for things like filter effects that blend content with the background. There may be other uses, but that's the one I know.

If you don't have it set, then technically the element can't use backgrounds created by ancestors.

The only major browser that supported it (ever) was IE10/11, so it doesn't get used very much (it's also there as boilerplate in every Illustrator SVG export—for no good reason).

Comment: I wasn't too shocked when this was no on caniuse.com. However it was shocking that the w3.org examples didn't work on chrome/mac. Go IE 10+ for finally being first.

Comment: Its deprecated i.e. nobody's going to implement it: http://www.w3.org/TR/filter-effects/#AccessBackgroundImage Illustrator rather ruinied it by putting it everywhere which means that a UA cannot use it in the way it was intended to be used. That and the fact that it was pretty much impossible to implement the spec as written ensured its demise.

Comment: Just wanted to mention IE11/Edge still support the feature, but we had to disable support when used on the root <svg> element due to Inkscape adding it on every file (causing perf issues). As of today, other browsers still do not support In1/In2=BackgroundImage though, only IE and Edge do.

Comment: +1 for "It's also there as boilerplate in every Illustrator SVG export - for no good reason." -- was wondering a colleague would add this attribute in this case; this explains it.

Answer (score 16):

As [noted by Robert Longson in comments](http://#comment40755915_21356393), attribute `enable-background` is [deprecated at least since 2014](https://www.w3.org/TR/filter-effects/#AccessBackgroundImage).

> SVG 1.1 introduced the enable-background property. The property defined the back drop under the filter region at the time that the `<filter>` element was invoked. The concept defined by this property was identified to be incompatible with the model of stacking context in CSS at the time writing this specification. UAs can choose to implement the enable-background property as defined in SVG 1.1 but will not be compatible to this specification or to CSS Compositing and Blending [W3C Working Draft].

Answer (score 2):

> **Deprecated:** This feature is no longer recommended. Though some browsers might still support it, it may have already been removed from the relevant web standards, may be in the process of being dropped, or may only be kept for compatibility purposes. Avoid using it, and update existing code if possible; see the [compatibility table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/enable-background#browser_compatibility) at the bottom of this page to guide your decision. Be aware that this feature may cease to work at any time.

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/enable-background)