# Why does SVG background color doesn't change in EDGE while scrolling?

Tags: javascript, svg, background-color, rgb, microsoft-edge

While scrolling I change the background color of SVG. From white to dark. It works fine in Chrome and firefox. The problem is with EDGE. Id doesn't apply the rule:

```
style="enable-background:new 0 0 556.08 1248;"
```

What I actually do is:

```
 const rightPlasts = document.querySelector('#right-plasts path');
 rightPlasts.setAttribute('fill', `rgb(${r}, ${g}, ${b}`);
```

EDITED: 
more code provided

```
  const sidebar = document.querySelector('#right-plasts path');

  window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
    const y = 1 + ((window.scrollY || window.pageYOffset) / 140);
    const [r, g, b] = [red / y, green / y, blue / y].map(Math.round);

    if (r >= 33) {
      sidebar.style.backgroundColor = `rgb(${r}, ${g}, ${b})`;

      const rightPlasts = document.querySelector('#right-plasts path');
      rightPlasts.setAttribute('fill', `rgb(${r}, ${g}, ${b}`);
    }
  });
```

Comment: Please read this answer [What exactly does the enable-background attribute do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21354116/what-exactly-does-the-enable-background-attribute-do#21356393). Also: can you add more code to your question? A working example would be great.

Comment: Could you post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). so that we could test it on our side, it might be easier for us to help you solve the problem.